# BIGSERIAL vs SERIAL in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, auto-increment, postgresql-serial

I'm new on PostgreSQL for auto-increment we have to use `BIGSERIAL` or `SERIAL`, so can anyone please explain which one we have to use when creating a table. Which one be the best please explain scenario wise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html):

```
serial      4 bytes     autoincrementing integer        1 to 2147483647
bigserial   8 bytes     large autoincrementing integer  1 to 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Which one we should use due to performance?

Comment: it depends on how many records you are expecting. If serial is enough, then take serial.

Answer (score 8):

There are **3 types of serials** in PostgreSQL as shown below:

| Name | Storage Size | Description | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **smallserial** | **2 bytes** | **small autoincrementing integer** | **1 to 32767** |
| **serial** | **4 bytes** | **autoincrementing integer** | **1 to 2147483647** |
| **bigserial** | **8 bytes** | **large autoincrementing integer** | **1 to 9223372036854775807** |